# IPv6 Multicast locally deployed pub/sub system, need to specify interface?

Tags: java, ipv6, multicast

So, I'm working in a distributed pub/sub system and trying to implement multicasting using Java.

Basically, I've got two locally deployed components on a VM, a temperature sensor and a subscriber.

The sensor publishes an event (through a datagram socket) using the multicast address ff7e:230:0:0:0:0:0:1234. The subscriber has a multicast socket that has joined the group with address ff7e:230:0:0:0:0:0:1234.

Problem is that the subscriber doesn't receive the packet. I've tested the same just using loopback addresses (the sensor publishing to ::1 and the subscriber listening to packets meant for ::1). Using wireshark I do notice that the vm is sending an event to ff7e:230:0:0:0:0:0:1234 but it isn't being 'sent' back or received by the subscriber.

I was wondering, do I need to specify the interface for the mlc communications? Using eth0 for example, do the addresses, and group, need to be ff7e:230:0:0:0:0:0:1234%eth0.

Any other things I should check?

Answer (score -1):

Try using two JVMs. From the kernel's point of view, the packets are sent by the JVM, and why should a sender's packets be echoed back to the very same process?

Comment: There's no evidence here that he *isn't* using two JVMs. Also you don't appear to have heard of multicast loopback.

Comment: I have heard of multicast loopback. Wireshark sees only the outgoing packet, though, so trying with two separate VMs is an easy and quick thing to test. Also, doesn't the question say "two components on a VM"? Perhaps I'm expecting more precision than is reasonable in ordinary language.